# Function calls another function but does not wait for return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a javascript function that basically calls another function. This other function returns true or false and then I have an if statement however the function does not wait for the value to be returned it just keeps plowing through the code. What is the solution around this?

So my first function has:

```
confirmmation = show_confirmation("<some text>", "245px");
    if (confirmmation) {
       return true;
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }
```

and that calls:

```
function show_confirmation(message, height) {
        var contentPosition = $('.content').position();
        var contentHeight = $('.content').height();
        var bottomPosition = contentPosition.top + contentHeight;
        $('.confirmBox').css("top", (bottomPosition - ($('.confirmBox').outerHeight()+100)) + "px");
        $('.confirmBox').css("left", (($('.content').width() - $('.confirmBox').outerWidth()) / 2) + $('.content').scrollLeft() + "px");
        $('.confirmBox').css("height", height);
        $('.confirmBox .confirmationMessage').html(message)
        $('.confirmBox').css("display", "block");

        $('#yesButton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.confirmBox').hide("slow");
            return true;
        });
        $('#noButton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.confirmBox').hide("slow");       
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: `show_confirmation` doesn't return anything. It establishes event handlers on the yes and no buttons, then returns. Those event handlers return when the user clicks on the buttons, but `show_confirmation` doesn't wait for that.

Comment: Are you expecting show_confirmation to return either true or false according to the click on the buttons? such ".click"s are event handlers ATTACHED to a DOM element, but the function won't stop until it gets something, you probably want to call a function inside both yesButton and noButton, passing that either true or false, that's probably what you wanted to do (or use a callback).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a callback:

```
function show_confirmation(message, height, callback) {
    // ...

    $('#yesButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.confirmBox').hide("slow");
        callback(true);
    });
    $('#noButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.confirmBox').hide("slow");
        callback(false);
    });
}

show_confirmation("<some text>", "245px", function(confirmation) {
    if (confirmation) {
        // yes button clicked
    }
    else {
        // no button clicked
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use callbacks. You can't feasibly have a blocking function in a browser.

Have your show_confirmation function take in a function argument that gets called with the return value.

Answer (score 1):

```
function show_confirmation(message, height, callback) {
        var contentPosition = $('.content').position();
        var contentHeight = $('.content').height();
        var bottomPosition = contentPosition.top + contentHeight;
        $('.confirmBox').css("top", (bottomPosition - ($('.confirmBox').outerHeight()+100)) + "px");
        $('.confirmBox').css("left", (($('.content').width() - $('.confirmBox').outerWidth()) / 2) + $('.content').scrollLeft() + "px");
        $('.confirmBox').css("height", height);
        $('.confirmBox .confirmationMessage').html(message)
        $('.confirmBox').css("display", "block");

        $('#yesButton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.confirmBox').hide("slow");
            callback(true);
        });
        $('#noButton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.confirmBox').hide("slow");  
            callback(false);     
        });
    }

function someAnotherFunction(value){
    if(value){
         //yesButton
    }else{
         //noButton
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
show_confirmation("message", 0, someAnotherFunction);
```